# Xamarin android Edittext.Focusable/Enabled not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which I want to disable in the beginning and enable later. the Problem is if I use EditText.Enabled the EditText still opens the Keyboard regardless of state (true or false). if I use EditText.Focusable the keyboard is not showing after I set it to false and back to true again. I want to be able to enable/disable the Edittext at runtime.

Comment: I tested it on Android 6.0, but failed to reproduce the issue, could you please provide your api level, And maybe test it  on emulator to check if the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you tried clean build?